# App takes a very long time to start after rebooting the device

Tags: android, autostart, android-reboot

My application is running in Kiosk mode, so the user cannot launch third-party applications. Also, my application is set to autoload after rebooting the smartphone. The application starts in the Kiosk mode after rebooting the smartphone.
The problem is that the launch of the application takes a long time and the user, if desired, can have time to launch some third-party programs.

After researching this issue, I realized that this is most likely related to the priority of starting services. System services/applications are loaded first, and then user applications are loaded. I found out in the sources that you can increase the priority of the application, but this [only](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/intent-filter-element#:%7E:text=In%20certain%20circumstances%20the%20requested%20priority%20is%20ignored%20and%20the%20value%20is%20capped%20to%200) works on privileged applications, otherwise the priority level is only 0.

Is it possible to somehow speed up the download of the application or transfer the application to the privileged category when installing the application?

Perhaps this will help. The application is the owner of the device and the installation takes place using a QR code after device wipe.

Comment: Is your app set as the launcher app?  If not it should be.  If your app is the launcher, then there is no opportunity to launch another app, because its shown as the home screen

Comment: @GabeSechan The application has not been set as a launcher application. Set it up and everything worked as it should. Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As advised by @GabeSechan I set my app as launcher. It's solved my problem

```
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```